# Fitting elements for Splash Page on mobile in BootStrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive splash page, but it's not responding, no matter how much I try to manipulate it. What I'm mostly trying to do is fit the image with no margin or padding. I want it similar to [Adele's](http://adele.com/) mobile site. Also, I'm not sure if the code is clean and I'm naming the classes correctly. I created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/erodriguez2385/pen/wKVMPP) so you can check it out there.

```
 <div class="featurette">
  <img class="featurette-image img-responsive pull-left center-block" src="http://www.placehold.it/400/F84065/000" alt="#">

  <div class="purchase-album">
    <div class="album">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.placehold.it/200/fa8ca2" />
      <div class="lead">available now:</div>
    </div>
    <div class="space">
    </div>
    <p class="lead text-center available "></p>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg outline" type="submit">iTunes</button>
    </a>

    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg outline" type="submit">loudr</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="enter">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg outline" type="submit">
    <a href="#"> enter</a>
  </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adeles page is a background image with the content displayed on top.

You can achieve this in many ways.

Try using this and playing about with the CSS to get everything in the desired place.

[codepen here example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaNRRO)

```
<header>
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="header-content-inner">
                    <h1>Your image here</h1>
            <p>buttons here etc</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Shrink the page to see the responsive-ness